# 'pd.read_csv' using variable size chunks: How to stop without try/except?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

`pd.read_csv(iterator=True)` returns an iterator of type `TextFileReader`. I need to call `TextFileReader.get_chunk` in order to specify the number of rows to return for each call.

```
import random
import pandas as pd

chunks = pd.read_csv('file.csv', iterator=True)

try:
    while True:
        chunk = chunks.get_chunk(random.randint(1,3))
        print(chunk)
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

**Question**: Is there a way to get rid of the try construction in this code? Said otherwise is there a condition to put in the while statement to indicate the iterator has no more rows to deliver?

Here is some csv content for tests:

> "Year", "Score", "Title"
> 1968,  86, "Greetings"
> 1970,  17, "Bloody Mama"
> 1971,  40, "Born to Win"
> 1973,  98, "Mean Streets"
> 1973,  88, "Bang the Drum Slowly"
> 1976,  41, "The Last Tycoon"
> 1976,  99, "Taxi Driver"

---

**Notes**

I know the `for` loop is designed to catch the `StopIteration` signal, and there is a way to iterate over `TextFileReader` returned by `pd.read_csv` but in this case I think I can't manage the variable number of rows returned, it must be fixed:

```
chunks = pd.read_csv('file.csv',chunksize=3)
for chunk in chunks:
    print(chunk)
```

Difficulties with the documentation:

For some reason the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.0/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) doesn't provide the documentation of `pandas.io.parsers.TextFileReader`, the only pseudo-documentation I found is from [kite](https://www.kite.com/python/docs/pandas.io.parsers.TextFileReader) site, and is mostly an empty shell.

It seems also `TextFileReader` has been a context manager at some time, and this could have been another solution. However this is not the case anymore, in spite the documentation still says it is one, and provides examples which don't work like:

```
with pd.read_csv("tmp.sv", sep="|", iterator=True) as reader:
    reader.get_chunk(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this piece of code would resolve your issue

Generators are much needed when you use chunks.

```
   def read():
    chunksize = 10000
    with open('Sample.csv','r') as f:
        while True:
            read_data = f.read(chunksize)
            if not read_data:
                break
            yield read_data
```

When you print the Function, you will get generator object `<generator object read_chunks.<locals>.read at 0x0000029DEE9F20C8>` You can iterate through `for` loop to get each row and you can convert it to Dataframe

Comment: Can you complete the code and add how the generator is called to deliver variable-size chunks until the eof? (using `for chunk in chunk_function()` leads to *The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous*)

Comment: I have edited the code here, Have a look at it.

Comment: As previously said, this code throws an error, because the line `read_data = f.read(chunksize)` returns a DataFrame, and you can't test a DataFrame for a Boolean value, as you do in `if not read_data`. Don't you have the same error when testing?

Comment: This Code doesn't throw an error for me. `read_data = f.read(chunksize)`  line returns a `String` not `DataFrame` . You can convert it into DataFrame from generator object.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in 3.8+, the walrus operator might be what you're looking for:

```py
import random

while (chunk := chunks.get_chunk(random.randint(1,3))):
    print(chunk)
```

Comment: "*The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous*". Are you able to run this code with pd.read_csv?

Comment: No, sorry, the only machine I have access to right now is on 3.7